# Magento 2 missing create shipment button

Tags: php, magento, nginx

I can't find the submit button for creating a shipment after an order is received. I tried several versions, 2.1.4, 2.1.3 and 2.0 but all of them won't display the required button. So I am thinking maybe it is something else that I am overlooking. I tried also different modes: default, developer, production without result. There is also a github issue about this [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8424)[image]

In my system.log I find the following exception:
main.CRITICAL: Renderer for type "simple" does not exist. [] []

Someone can point me out what this could possibly mean?